Do I need paragraph numbers when citing a webpage?
I know that when you need to cite a specific paragraph of a webpage, you use the paragraph number instead of page numbers.
However, in what instances are paragraph numbers even necessary? Most references to webpages I see do not use any location data at all beyond the URL.
(I am using APA-7 format, since there is not a specific tag for that.)

Following APA, when you cite from material that does not have page numbers, such as webpages, you may provide the paragraph number or a heading or section name or both.
https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/quotations/no-page-numbers

Recently, I've been working on editing a Master's thesis for a friend. The university's technical reader says to use paragraphs. How should I proceed with the editing?

NVM, I wrote my comment before the edit.

If the university's technical reader says to use paragraphs, you should follow the rules laid down in the university's 'technical reader'… whatever you or your university mean by a 'technical reader'.
How paragraphs in articles or books or web pages are cited is down first to house style - here, your technical reader and failing that, to the author.
I suggest you either ask a relevant senior, or make your own choice or preferably, both.
